# Slick Carousel - determine last element in carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I started using Slick Carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for my project. 
Is there a method or property, where I can check that my carousel reached last element? Or find, what is current item?

I would like to be able to insert new elements with AJAX as soon as user reaches last element in carousel.

What I want to achieve, is something like infinite lazy loading. It is something like calendar view, where initially only current week is loaded, and as soon as user scrolls past Friday, I want to load next week.

Comment: Where you able to get the solution ? If so please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the docs for lazy loading. From what you're asking for it sounds like this would work perfect.

From the docs:

```
// To use lazy loading, set a data-lazy attribute
// on your img tags and leave off the src

<img data-lazy="img/lazyfonz1.png"/>

$('.lazy').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

So I'm guessing that for new images you want to append, just give them the `data-lazy` attribute. Hope this will help, but maybe you already saw the lazy loading example and are looking for something completely different :)

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for, because I prefer to use AJAX call to get html, and it is text, not images. Also, URL is determined in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine, if user has reached last element, is to find all elements that have `slick-slide` class, and then check if last one of them has `slick-active` class.

For this to work, in slick initializer give property `infinite: false`. Otherwise elements are cloned.